# Deleting Mysql rows with checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, sql-delete

I've got a page where I render a table of values from Mysql using PHP and HTML.

I want to delete rows checked with a checkbox upon clicking a delete button. Unfortunately, nothing happens when clicking the button and I'm at a total loss as to where to look.

Code is below (database connection has been omitted, but it works).

```
<body>

<?php
$delete = $_POST['checkbox'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM Cards";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Color</td><td>Type</td></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]" . $row['id'] . "]'></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Color'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['CardType'] . "</td></tr>";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
echo "</table>";
?>

</body>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center"><input name="delete" type="SUBMIT" id="delete" value="delete" action="POST"></td>
</tr>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $count = count($checkbox);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $id = (int) $checkbox[$i]; // Parse your value to integer

        if ($id > 0) { // and check if it's bigger then 0
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM Cards WHERE id = $id");
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php include "../footer.htm";?>
```

Comment: Wrap your input elements in a `<form>......</form>

Comment: That doesn't work (although it does refresh the page when clicking delete!).

Comment: check this http://vsc-project.blogspot.in/2012/08/delete-record-using-php-mysql-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<body>

<?php

$connect=mysqli_connect("Host","Username","Password","Database"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY DATA */

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $count = count($checkbox);

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

        if(!empty($checkbox[$i])){ /* CHECK IF CHECKBOX IS CLICKED OR NOT */

        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$checkbox[$i]); /* ESCAPE STRINGS */
        mysqli_query($connect,"DELETE FROM Cards WHERE id = '$id'"); /* EXECUTE QUERY AND USE ' ' (apostrophe) IN YOUR VARIABLE */

        } /* END OF IF NOT EMPTY CHECKBOX */

    } /* END OF FOR LOOP */

} /* END OF ISSET DELETE */

$query = "SELECT * FROM Cards"; /* SELECT FROM Cards TABLE */
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query); /* EXECUTE QUERY */

echo "<form action='' method='POST'>"; /* SUBMIT PAGE ON ITSELF */

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Color</td><td>Type</td></tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ /* FETCH ARRAY */
    $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$row['id']);
    echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='$id'></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Color'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['CardType'] . "</td></tr>";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
echo "</table>";
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center"><input name="delete" type="SUBMIT" id="delete" value="delete" action="POST"></td>
</tr>
</form>

<?php include "../footer.htm";?>
</body>
```

- I've converted your code to **MySQLi** from the deprecated **MySQL**.
- And used *empty()* function to determine a checked checkbox.
- You forgot to put a `<form>` function for your html.
- And also forgot to use value tag for your checkbox.

I have put explanations quoted in /* */ inside the code I have provided.

Comment: Hey, thanks! That looks great. Unfortunately, nothing happens when clicking the "delete" button. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Have you try my updated answer? Try to use it again, and come back to me for the result

Comment: Yep, using it exactly as written (substituting my DB connection info), and nothing happens. Clicking delete with a box or two checked refreshes the page, but no deletions.

Comment: Updated it again. I saw your input type checkbox doesn't have a value tag. Try it again.

Comment: Awesome! Works flawlessly! Thanks so much for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<body>

<?php
$delete = $_POST['checkbox'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM Cards";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<form method=post action=''>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>Name</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Color</td>
          <td>Type</td></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $content .= <<< END
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="{$row['id']}"></td>
        <td>{$row['Name']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Quantity']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Color']}</td>
        <td>{$row['CardType']}</td>
    </tr>
END;
}
echo $content;
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center"><input name="delete" type="SUBMIT" id="delete" value="delete"></td>
</tr>
</table></form>
</body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

    foreach($checkbox as $id) {

        $id = (int) $id;

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM Cards WHERE id = $id");


    }

}
?>

<?php include "../footer.htm";?>
```

Comment: Try to use mysqli_* functions. mysql_* functions going to deprecated.